# Tkinker button function not working as desired

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I've just started my first attempts in coding lately and wanted to do this little app for a challenge, basically it's meant to

1. Generate a hex colour on click
2. Show it as a value and display a real color.

I can generate the value, show it and apply a colour, but only at launch and cannot get the button working (ideally you could spam it as long as you want generating new results.)

```
import random as rd
import tkinter as tk

values = ["0", "1", "2", "3","4", "5","6", "7","8", "9","A", "B","C", "D","E", "F"]

root = tk.Tk()

def generate():
    rd.shuffle(values)
    return (f"#{values[0]}{values[1]}{values[2]}{values[3]}{values[4]}{values[5]}")


valTest = generate()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width=600)
canvas.pack()
canvas.update()
kolor = tk.Label(root, text=generate())
kolor.pack()

canvas['bg'] = generate()

Generuj = tk.Button(root, text="Generuj", height=80, width=60, bg="white", fg="black", 
                    command=generate)
Generuj.pack()
Generuj.invoke()
canvas.update_idletasks()

root.mainloop()
```

I don't know what to google at this point.

Comment: Please avoid using of teenage slang here—this isn't a social media site. What do you mean by "spam it"? Please clarify what a "working button" would do, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Your button only generates a value, but never assigns it.

Make a new function for assignment like this:

```py
def updatebg():
    canvas['bg'] = generate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `canvas` and `kolor` inside `generate()`.  Also, simply use `random.randint()` instead of `random.shuffle()`:

```py
import random as rd
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def generate():
    color = rd.randint(0, 0xffffff)
    hex_color = f"#{color:06x}"
    canvas.config(bg=hex_color)
    kolor.config(text=hex_color)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width=600)
canvas.pack()

kolor = tk.Label(root)
kolor.pack()

Generuj = tk.Button(root, text="Generuj", height=8, width=60, bg="white", fg="black", command=generate)
Generuj.pack()

generate() # show first random color

root.mainloop()
```